# sudo twice become method for Ansible

Tags: linux, sudo, ansible

I have to deal with a setup in "/etc/sudoers" that I can't change because the servers in question are managed by a different team and they don't want to change it.

I have root access only by sudoing to another account first. My account is only allowed to run the specific command "sudo su - admin" (no additional arguments can be appended). Then, as user "admin", I can run any root commands normally with sudo (e.g., "sudo vi /etc/shadow", etc.) or open a root shell with "sudo -s" or "sudo su -", etc.

I want to run Ansible ad-hoc commands and playbooks as root (e.g., "become: yes") on these servers from a different server that I control, but it would require that Ansible first run "sudo su - admin", then run the normal "sudo" command.

I know you can create custom become methods. This seems to me the way to solve this problem, but the specific solution is beyond me. Can anyone help with this?

BTW, if it helps, "NOPASSWD:" is set for both my account and "admin" in "/etc/sudoers".

Comment: Can you install ansible on the server? I'd try to install it and then run the playbook on the server as the `admin` user, so you only need to `sudo` once...